# Measuring the performance of a single instance life cycle in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance

My program (C#) is composed of a static class which sends out messages (basically acts like a data-feed) and many individual class instances which listens on those messages and when encounter one that got their id on, do some calculations and raise another event. I want to measure what resource does each instance of these listener class takes during waiting and calculations so I can asses how many instances I can create simultaneously.

I only know the basic use of VS profiler and would like to find further references on how to achieve this kind of tests.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I know about profiling software. What I am looking for is the method of measuring only a single class instance within the application.

Comment: Be careful; something static with an event that talks to instances sounds like an ideal way to accidentally extend lifetimes - *essentially* a memory leak (it will block garbage collection of anything still subscribed). You will have to be insanely paranoid about unsubscribing events if you keep this approach.

Comment: I am aware of the problematics of that - but how can I be insanely paranoid? any guidelines for that?

Comment: what Marc meant was that you'd have to take a lot of trouble to ensure that your instances are un-subscribing from the events they've subscribed to. In other words you'll have to go through a lot of trouble and testing (that's not worth it), for no apparent benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the in built VS profiler as I fell in love with dotTrace on VS 2008. Give it a go, it is very accurate and granular in both memory usage and processor usage.

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/

Comment: Thank you Hawxby, but can dotTrace attach itself to a single class instance or something similar to that?

Comment: I believe so although you may need to have a dig through the different threads to find individual calls to the class instance.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/